# CakePHP hasAndBelongsToMany Checkbox matrix

Tags: php, cakephp, checkbox, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two models, `Component` and `Group`. A `Group` has many `Component`s, and a `Component` can be in many `Group`s. Now, what I need is a view, in which there's a table, `n` times `m` field (or matrix) of checkboxes. The Columns would be all the `Group`s (which would be fewer) and the rows would represent the `Component`. Basically, when the HaBTM-Relationship exists, the checkbox is checked.

This should be editable, meaning it would be wrapped in a form.

```
      | Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3
 C1   |    x    |         |   x
 C2   |    x    |    x    |
 C3   |         |         |   x
```

What is the least stressful way to achieve this in CakePHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright.
First of course you load the data from your connecting table. So you get a lot of datasets like:

```
id => 4
component_id => 4
group_id =>3
```

Then you have an array of all existing components and another one which contains all existing groups.

Since you have the components in rows I would reorganise this array of arrays, so that you have a multidimensional array which as first key has the component_id and under this id you have an array containing the arrays of all datasets, which contain this group.

e.g.:

```
array(
1 => array(
    0 => array(
    'id' => 4,
    'component_id' => 1,
    'group_id' => 2,
    ),
    1 => array(
    'id' => 4,
    'component_id' => 1,
    'group_id' => 5,
    ),
    ),
2 => array(
    0 => array(
    'id' => 4,
    'component_id' => 2,
    'group_id' => 1,
    ),
    1 => array(
    'id' => 4,
    'component_id' => 2,
    'group_id' => 3,
    ),
    ),
);
```

After this reorganisation you can pass it to the view, where you can iterate through it to build the form, giving each checkbox the component-group info, which you can collect after sending the form.

Nicer than that (as a version 1.2) would be a AJAX call which saves the combination immediately after activating or deactivating the checkbox. Your choice ;)

Calamity Jane

Comment: Well I tried something silimar but had to realize, this won't remove the old entries, only makes sure new ones can be added. I guess there is no short cut do doing this by foot - delete the old entries and go through the matrix each by each.

Comment: I hav a similar problem in my application and what I did is writing a method in my model which does that:

Comment: writing a method in my connecting model which does that:
It saves first the new connections and then removes the ones which are deactivated.
If you are interested I can paste the code here.